# Convert a nested dict into a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data  = {
    "body-1": {
        "funtion-definition": ".c file",
        "funtion-definition-2": ".c file-2"
    },
    "body-2": {
        "funtion-definition": ".c file",
        "funtion-definition-2": ".c file-2"
    }
}
```

This has to format as

```
Group     function definiton     .c file
body-1    funtion-definition     .c file
          funtion-definition-2   .c file-2      
body-2    funtion-definition     .c file
          funtion-definition-2   .c file-2
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = (pd.DataFrame(data).unstack()
         .rename_axis(['Group', 'function definiton'])
         .reset_index(name='.c file')
      )
```

Output:

```
    Group    function definiton    .c file
0  body-1    funtion-definition    .c file
1  body-1  funtion-definition-2  .c file-2
2  body-2    funtion-definition    .c file
3  body-2  funtion-definition-2  .c file-2
```